# How to install HANA DB on Oracle Linux 7?

Tags: linux, installation, sap-hana

I want to know how to install SAP HANA DB 2.0 on Oracle Linux 7 including downloading, installing and the first connection establishing to the system from network. I've spent a few hours to find out how to do it, but haven't found all required information in one place.

Answer (score 0):

1. To download SAP HANA DB server you need to download **SAP HANA, Express Edition Download Manager** first, because there's no direct links available for this server downloading.

   - For this [Go through express edition registration first](https://www.sap.com/cmp/td/sap-hana-express-edition.html).
     [image]
   - Go to your mailbox and click the link for account activation
   - Confirm usage terms and you'll see the next window where you could
     [download **DM**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Py4.png)
2. Open **Download Manager**, specify **Image** as **Binary Installer**. If you use Windows as your desktop system, you could additionally select **Clients (Windows)** to connect to HANA server using hana client for windows ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL2L5.png)). Click **Download** to download required packages.
3. Copy **hxe.tgz** archive to Oracle Linux system. (I've put installer to shared folder on windows, and added this folder to `/etc/fstab` on Linux the next way:

   ```
   //MyIPAddress/winshare /mnt/winshare cifs username=myuser,password=mypassword,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
   ```

   `/mnt/winshare` should be created first: `sudo mkdir /mnt/winshare`. And if you've just added it, you need to mount it: `sudo mount /mnt/winshare`

   Copy: `cp /mnt/winshare/hxe.tgz /tmp`
4. Go to `/tmp` folder and extract it:

   ```
   $ cd /temp && tar xvfz ./hxe.tgz
   ```
5. Go to `/tmp/HANA_EXPRESS_20/DATA_UNITS/HDB_SERVER_LINUX_X86_64` folder and run command line installer using administrator privileges:

   ```
   $ sudo ./hdblcm
   ```
6. Select **install** and **server**:

   ```
    SAP HANA Lifecycle Management - SAP HANA Express Edition 2.00.045.00.1575639312
    *******************************************************************************



    Choose an action

      Index | Action            | Description
      ----------------------------------------------
      1     | install           | Install new system
      2     | Exit (do nothing) |

    Enter selected action index [2]: 1


    SAP HANA Database version '2.00.045.00.1575639312' will be installed.

    Select additional components for installation:

      Index | Components | Description
      ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1     | all        | All components
      2     | server     | No additional components
      3     | afl        | Install SAP HANA AFL (incl.PAL,BFL,OFL) version 2.00.045.
      4     | epmmds     | Install SAP HANA EPM-MDS version 2.00.045.0000.1575663037

    Enter comma-separated list of the selected indices [1]: 2
    Enter Installation Path [/hana/shared]:
    Enter Local Host Name [hana]:
    Enter SAP HANA System ID [HXE]:
    Enter Instance Number [90]:
    Enter Master Password:
    Confirm Master Password:
    Enter ID of User Group (sapsys) [79]:


    ...
    Do you want to continue? (y/n): y
    ...


    Regenerating SSL certificates...
    Deploying SAP Host Agent configurations...
    Creating Component List...
    SAP HANA Express Edition System installed
   ```
7. Enable HANA DB port in firewall if you want to connect to it from network as it is in my case:

   ```
    $ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=39015/tcp
    $ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
   ```
8. Check connection from windows using telnet:

   ```
    telnet MyHanaDBServerIP 39015
   ```
9. Go to folder where you've downloaded **hdb_client_windows_x86_64.zip** archive, extract it, go to **HDB_CLIENT_WINDOWS_X86_64** folder, run **hdbsetup.exe** installer and install the client
10. Open windows cmd and go to the location where you've installed the client: `cd "c:\Program Files\sap\hdbclient"` and run the next command to test connection to server:

    ```
    hdbsql.exe -n MyHanaDBServerIP:39015 -i 90 -u SYSTEM
    ```

    and execute a test select query:

    ```
    select * from "SYS"."M_DATABASES";
    ```

    [image: cmd image with commands]

    Here I used password specified during installation.

    Use `$ su - hxeadm` on your linux server to have access to HANA DB Server environment's variables, paths, utils.